# I create a Database and a table for saving data. But when I exit from app and run again my data have been stored before not exists at all?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am new in android.I wanting store my audio data to a database. I can create Database and a table fore saving data.but problem is when I exit from app and run again my data have been stored before not exists at all.
I need those data saved before.but I have this issue with my database.i am certain that data stored truly.
May be problem it is that every time I run app,database overwrite on existing database.actually what is issue?
Your help make me happy.thanks.
Here is my classes which I used and truly worked.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;
public class MySqilteOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
{

public static final String TABLE_AUDIOS = "audios";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
public static final String COLUMN_fORMAT = "format";
public static final String COLUMN_PATH = "path";
public static final String COLUMN_TOTAL_TIME = "total_time";
public static final String COLUMN_SIZE = "size";
public static final String COLUMN_CREATEDATE = "create_date";
public static final String COLUMN_CREATETIME= "create_time";
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "my_database.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;  
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
    + TABLE_AUDIOS + "(" + COLUMN_ID
    + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN_NAME
    + " text not null, " + COLUMN_fORMAT + " text not null, " +COLUMN_PATH + " text not null, " + COLUMN_TOTAL_TIME + " text not null, " + COLUMN_SIZE + " text not null, " +  COLUMN_CREATETIME + " text not null, "+COLUMN_CREATEDATE + " text not null);";

public MySqilteOpenHelper(Context context) 
{
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    Log.d("database create statement:", DATABASE_CREATE);       
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database)
{
    database.execSQL( ""+DATABASE_CREATE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
{
    Log.w(MySqilteOpenHelper.class.getName(),
            "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion +
            " to "
            + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_AUDIOS);
            onCreate(database);

}
```

}

And this is a class which by that can insert and get rows.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.util.Log;

public class Interface_For_UpgradingAudiosTable
{
private SQLiteDatabase database;
private MySqilteOpenHelper dbHelper;
private String[] allColumns = { MySqilteOpenHelper.COLUMN_ID,
MySqilteOpenHelper.COLUMN_NAME,
MySqilteOpenHelper.COLUMN_fORMAT,MySqilteOpenHelper.COLUMN_PATH ,MySqilteOpenHelper.COLUMN_TOTAL_TIME ,MySqilteOpenHelper.COLUMN_SIZE , MySqilteOpenHelper.COLUMN_CREATETIME , MySqilteOpenHelper.COLUMN_CREATEDATE  };

private String[] mycolumns={MySqilteOpenHelper.COLUMN_NAME,
        MySqilteOpenHelper.COLUMN_fORMAT,MySqilteOpenHelper.COLUMN_PATH ,MySqilteOpenHelper.COLUMN_TOTAL_TIME ,MySqilteOpenHelper.COLUMN_SIZE , MySqilteOpenHelper.COLUMN_CREATETIME , MySqilteOpenHelper.COLUMN_CREATEDATE  };

public Interface_For_UpgradingAudiosTable(Context context)
{

    dbHelper = new MySqilteOpenHelper(context);
}

public void open() throws SQLException 
{
    database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

public void close() 
{
    dbHelper.close();
}

public StructureDetails createAudio(StructureDetails sd) 
{
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(MySqilteOpenHelper.COLUMN_NAME, sd.getName());
    values.put(MySqilteOpenHelper.COLUMN_fORMAT, sd.getFormat());
    values.put(MySqilteOpenHelper.COLUMN_PATH, sd.getPath());
    values.put(MySqilteOpenHelper.COLUMN_TOTAL_TIME, sd.getTotalTime());
    values.put(MySqilteOpenHelper.COLUMN_SIZE, sd.getSize());
    values.put(MySqilteOpenHelper.COLUMN_CREATETIME, sd.getCreateTime());
    values.put(MySqilteOpenHelper.COLUMN_CREATEDATE, sd.getCreateDate());

    long insertId = database.insert(MySqilteOpenHelper.TABLE_AUDIOS,null,values);
    Log.d("insert iddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd:",insertId+"");
    Cursor cursor = database.query(MySqilteOpenHelper.TABLE_AUDIOS,
    allColumns, MySqilteOpenHelper.COLUMN_ID + " = " +
    insertId, null,
    null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    StructureDetails newAudio = cursorToAudio(cursor);
    cursor.close();
    return newAudio;
}

/*public void deleteAudio(StructureDetails Audio) 
{
    String path = Audio.getPath();
    System.out.println("Comment deleted with id: " + path);
    database.delete(MySqilteOpenHelper.TABLE_AUDIOS,
    MySqilteOpenHelper.COLUMN_PATH
    + " = " + path, null);
}*/

public ArrayList<StructureDetails> getAllAudiosFromDb() 
{
    List<StructureDetails> audiosList = new ArrayList<StructureDetails>();
    Log.d("errorrrrrrrrrrrr in get allllll", "");
    Cursor cursor = database.query(MySqilteOpenHelper.TABLE_AUDIOS,
            allColumns, null, null, null, null, null);
    if(!cursor.moveToFirst())
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) 
    {
        StructureDetails audio = cursorToAudio(cursor);
        audiosList.add(audio);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    // Make sure to close the cursor
    cursor.close();
    return (ArrayList<StructureDetails>) audiosList;
}

private StructureDetails cursorToAudio(Cursor cursor) 
{
    StructureDetails Audio = new StructureDetails();
    Audio.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
    Audio.setName(cursor.getString(1));
    Audio.setFormat(cursor.getString(2));
    Audio.setPath(cursor.getString(3));
    Audio.setTotalTime(cursor.getString(4));
    Audio.setSize(cursor.getString(5));
    Audio.setCreateTime(cursor.getString(6));
    Audio.setCreateDate(cursor.getString(7));
    return Audio;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my database worked truely if I had this code insted above code:

```
enter code herepublic ArrayList<StructureDetails> getAllAudiosFromDb() 
{
List<StructureDetails> audiosList = new ArrayList<StructureDetails>();
Log.d("errorrrrrrrrrrrr in get allllll", "");
Cursor cursor = database.query(MySqilteOpenHelper.TABLE_AUDIOS,
        allColumns, null, null, null, null, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();// this is changed!
while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) 
{
    StructureDetails audio = cursorToAudio(cursor);
    audiosList.add(audio);
    cursor.moveToNext();
}
// Make sure to close the cursor
cursor.close();
return (ArrayList<StructureDetails>) audiosList;
```

}

And above answer by "Arju" may be helpful.Neve eless I think I had problem on my method "getAllAudiosFromDb".may be this helped u.

Answer (score 1):

Change `create table` to `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` Otherwise your table will be create every time and data will be lost

So it must be

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
+ TABLE_AUDIOS + "(" + COLUMN_ID
+ " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN_NAME
+ " text not null, " + COLUMN_fORMAT + " text not null, " +COLUMN_PATH + " text not null, " + COLUMN_TOTAL_TIME + " text not null, " + COLUMN_SIZE + " text not null, " +  COLUMN_CREATETIME + " text not null, "+COLUMN_CREATEDATE + " text not null);";
```

**UPDATE**

`onCreate()` and `onUpgrade()` methods are really called the first time when Db is created. In facts, it's checked in `getReadableDatabase()` or `getWritebleDatabase()` methods of SQLiteOpenHelper. It will check if the DB already exist on the data directory and what is it's version. According to this it will either call `onCreate()`, or `onUpgrade()` Or nothing, if db file exist in correct version.

You can search your code for executing `myDBHelper.getReadable(Writable)Database()`. That is the time when this check will be performed.

Comment: thank u Arju. but database what? dosnt my database on exsiting database aftar each run?

Comment: sure.but another question: do you means that I havent to check exsiting my db??

Comment: No, it will be done by sqliteopenhelper itself, you dont want to worry about that

Comment: I remember your help dear.